# Finding a proper sequence

Tags: analysis

The following function was given to me $$f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor+\lfloor-x\rfloor$$

wherein $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the floor function of $x$. I was asked to select a proper sequence for showing that this function has no limit at $\infty$.

Honestly, my knowledge about analysis is weak. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $$f(n)=[n]+[-n]=n-n=0, \quad n\in\mathbb{N},$$ and then take $$f\left(\frac{2n+1}{2}\right)=n+(-n-1)=-1, \quad n\in\mathbb N$$

Then you have two different sequences with different limits when $\,n\to\infty\,$ and thus the limit at $\,\infty\,$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you Don, you saved me not to blush with my student.

Comment: So, according to your selected sequences, can we say if Limit$_{x\rightarrow\infty}a_n=\infty$ and $\{f(a_n)\}$ is convergent, we have Limit$_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)$ undefined?

Comment: @BabakSorouh Yes, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Limit_of_a_function_in_terms_of_sequences)